# Strange vertical lines on X-axis direction of parts

Tags: print-quality, fdm, creality-cr-10, x-axis

This one is turning out to be a real head-scratcher. I'm running a stock Creality CR-10S and there seems to be a single line approx 45° across the print on the X-axis direction.

I have attached images to better explain. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This are probably wrong theories, so let's exclude them: Does this anyhow correlate with an infill pattern (here I think of "Infill overlap (%)" setting) or with the starting point of print for the outer wall (a Z-seam, you would need to observe during the print)?

Comment: Do you print Infill before walls? Can you print a copy of that item and *abort* that print mid-way, showing the infill together with the erroneous area? On the black item, the seams are on the upper or lower edge afaict.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. These parts are hollow, and infill for both are concentric. Does it have to do with belt tension or motor vibrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your slicer check your z-seam overlap. Lines like that are what happens when a slicer is systematically trying to hide a seam while not adding a ton of time onto the print by adding in a bunch of additional time for travel.

Comment: This seemed to be the case, I was using matterhacker for slice and print. Didn't have this issue with Cura. Thanks a lot mate!